# TS: How to handle multiple possible types on a single type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

I have an Modal Data Interface

```js
interface ModalData {
 ...
 payload: any; // At any given time, this payload might be a string or number or boolean;
 ...
}
```

In the modal data payload have a possibility of different types, so for that I had created another type:

```js
type IPayLoad = string | number | boolean;
```

Now when I use this types on my code I'm getting the below errors.

The problem is I don't like setting the `any` type to payload above.
But if I set it to the type `IPayLoad`, I'm getting the below errors.

```js
this.service.saveString(modal.payload) // Argument of type 'IPayLoad' id not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

this.service.saveNumber(modal.payload) // Argument of type 'IPayLoad' id not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

this.service.saveBool(modal.payload) // Argument of type 'IPayLoad' id not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.
```

The calling functions in the service are here below:

```js
public saveString(res: string): void {}

public saveNumber(res: number): void {}

public saveBool(res: boolean): void {}
```

Comment: How do you know which method to call?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have set the type of `ModalData.payload` to `IPayLoad` instead of `any`, you'll need to narrow down the union type like this:

```js
if (typeof modal.payload === 'string') {
    saveString(modal.payload)
} else if (typeof modal.payload === 'number') {
    saveNumber(modal.payload)
} else if (typeof modal.payload === 'boolean') {
    saveBool(modal.payload)
}
```

The `typeof`-checks are called type guards, which you can read more about in the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use one method that accepts `IPayload` or `string|boolean|number` type.

But if you really want to use those three functions,

You can do as the following:

```js
this.service.saveString(`${payload}`);

this.service.saveNumber(Number(payload));

this.service.saveBoolean(Boolean(payload));
```

Comment: Thank you @bravemaster, but what if the types become more complex objects rather than pre-defined types as above?

Comment: @superbadcodemonkey has a more relevant answer. Please refer to it. But you need to combine all of them in one function that accepts `IPayload` type and do type checking.

Answer (score -1):

The keyword `as` solves the problem here.

```js
public getLoad (payload: IPayLoad) {

  this.service.saveString(payload as string);

  this.service.saveNumber(payload as number);

  this.service.saveBoolean(payload as boolean);

}
```

Comment: This is **not** type-safe in any way, please don't do this.